# How do I get the content-length header for jQuery AJAX POST success object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

I have a jQuery AJAX call that appends a URL's page into a selector. I want to monitor the progress of the page being appended:

```
$.ajax({
        
    url: URL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        page: 'page'
    },
    dataType: 'HTML',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    xhr: 
    function() {
    
        var XHR = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        
        XHR.upload.addEventListener('loadstart', HandleXHR); // Upload has begun
        XHR.upload.addEventListener('progress', HandleXHR); // Periodically indicates the amount of progress made so far
        XHR.upload.addEventListener('error', HandleXHR); // Upload failed due to an error
        XHR.upload.addEventListener('abort', HandleXHR); // Upload operation was aborted
        XHR.upload.addEventListener('load', HandleXHR); // Upload completed successfully
        XHR.upload.addEventListener('loadend', HandleXHR); // Upload finished
    
        function HandleXHR(event) {
            
            if(event.lengthComputable) {
                
                PercentProgress = Math.floor((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
        
                console.log(PercentProgress); // Returns 'Content-Length' header of data object (above)
        
            }
        
        }
        
        return XHR;
    
    },
    success: 
    function(data) {

        console.log(data.length); // Returns more accurate number (probably what I want)
            
        $('.selector').html(data);
        
    }
                
});
```

How do I compute the correct header *Content-Length* information in the XHR object to show the progress status of the AJAX call success object as apposed to the header *Content-Length* of the data object [that I'm already getting]?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent) `event.total` comes from the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: what other `Content-Length` are you talking about? Do you mean the data that you're sending to the server?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I guess I do. Sorry. How do I get the download and upload progress of the data being sent to the server and back?

Comment: I don't think you can get the upload progress.

Comment: You're just uploading the parameter `page=page`. That should be practically instantaneous.

Comment: Darn! So is there any way I can monitor the download progress of the data being downloaded from the server? The _content-length_ header is just giving me the length of the data object (in the above example 9 bytes) whereas I'd like the data being uploaded to the selector (the page declared in the URL object).

Comment: @Barmar I think what I'm asking is how can I get the progress of the data coming from the server?

Comment: There may not be a `Content-Length` header. That can only be sent if the server knows the length before it sends anything. If it's generated dynamically it doesn't know the length.

Comment: @Barmar To clarify, there’s no way to monitor the progress of XHR data from the server? I’m surprised - thanks

Comment: There is, you're doing it with the `progress` event.

Comment: Yeah but the content-length im getting with that progress event is way too short and reaches event.total before the data is done loading

Comment: If there's no content-length, it will just send the same value as `loaded` every time.

Comment: You can't get a percentage if it doesn't know how long the whole response is.